# Updating data into multiple Table -> MultipleObjectsReturned at /client/update-client

Tags: python, django

I am trying to update the data into 3 tables. I have not set up the primary-foreign key relation bcoz of project requirement. 
I got this error -

> MultipleObjectsReturned at /client/update-client get() returned more
>   than one BankDetails -- it returned 2!

from views, I'm sending the data into 3 models but its updating one table only.

> Views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_client_details(request):
    # try:
    client_master_dict = []
    client_master_dict = json.loads(request.body)
    client_data_bank = client_master_dict['data'][0]['bank_details']
    client_data_doc = client_master_dict['data'][0]['document_details']
    records, client_id = ClientDetails.update_client(client_master_dict['data'][0])
    for i in range(len(client_master_dict['data'][0]['bank_details'])):
        bank_data = BankDetails.update_bank_detail(client_data_bank[i],client_id)
    for j in range(len(client_master_dict['data'][0]['document_details'])):    
        document_data = DocumentDetails.update_document_detail(client_data_doc[j],client_id)
    datum = json.dumps(records)
    data = json.loads(datum)
    returnObject = {
        "status" : messages.SUCCESS,
        "message" : messages.CLIENT_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
        "results" : data 
    }
    return JsonResponse(returnObject,safe=False)
```

> Models.py (ClientDetails Table)

```
@classmethod
def update_client(cls, cilent_master_dict):
    # try:
        client_id = cilent_master_dict['client_id']
        client_obj = cls.objects.get(client_id = client_id)
        client_obj.client_name = cilent_master_dict['client_name']
        client_obj.client_pan_no = cilent_master_dict['client_pan_no']
        client_obj.client_adhar_no = cilent_master_dict['client_adhar_no']
        client_obj.legal_entity_name = cilent_master_dict['legal_entity_name'] 
        client_obj.credit_period = cilent_master_dict['credit_period']
        client_obj.client_tin_no = cilent_master_dict['client_tin_no']
        client_obj.client_email_id = cilent_master_dict['client_email_id']
        client_obj.head_office_name = cilent_master_dict['head_office_name']
        client_obj.office_contact = cilent_master_dict['office_contact']
        client_obj.office_name = cilent_master_dict['office_name'] 
        client_obj.office_email_id = cilent_master_dict['office_email_id'] 
        client_obj.gst_number = cilent_master_dict['gst_number']
        client_obj.office_country = cilent_master_dict['office_country'] 
        client_obj.office_state = cilent_master_dict['office_state']
        client_obj.office_district = cilent_master_dict['office_district'] 
        client_obj.office_taluka = cilent_master_dict['office_taluka']
        client_obj.office_city = cilent_master_dict['office_city'] 
        client_obj.office_street = cilent_master_dict['office_street']
        client_obj.office_state = cilent_master_dict['office_state']
        client_obj.office_pincode = cilent_master_dict['office_pincode']
        client_obj.contact_person_name = cilent_master_dict['contact_person_name']
        client_obj.contact_person_designation = cilent_master_dict['contact_person_designation']
        client_obj.contact_person_number = cilent_master_dict['contact_person_number']
        client_obj.contact_person_email = cilent_master_dict['contact_person_email']
        client_obj.contact_person_mobile = cilent_master_dict['contact_person_mobile']  
        client_obj.created_at = timezone.now()
        client_obj.created_by = cilent_master_dict['created_by'] 
        client_obj.updated_at = timezone.now() 
        client_obj.updated_by = cilent_master_dict['updated_by'] 
        client_obj.save()
        return cilent_master_dict, client_obj.client_id
```

> Models.py (BankDetails table)

```
@classmethod
def update_bank_detail(cls, client_master_dict):
    # try:
        print("bank data in update<<",client_master_dict)
        bank_details_id = client_master_dict[0]['user_id']
        bank_obj = cls.objects.filter(user_id = bank_details_id)
        bank_obj.__dict__.update(client_master_dict)
        bank_obj.save()
```

Models.py (Document Details)

```
 @classmethod
    def update_document_detail(cls, client_master_dict):   
        # try:
            client_id = client_master_dict[0]['user_id']
            doc_obj = cls.objects.filter(user_id = client_id)  
            doc_obj.__dict__.update(client_master_dict)
            doc_obj.save()
            return True
```

While sending the request data is updating on ClientDetails table only but not in BankDetails & DocumentDetails. It's giving an error **Multiple Objects** returns.

> Request Object:

```
{
    "data" : [
                {
                    "client_id":"CL15664751132746806000",
                    "client_name": "Kalki patil",
                    "client_pan_no":"RGBB004A11",
                    "client_adhar_no":"12312312313",
                    "legal_entity_name":"ABC",
                    "credit_period":"6 months",
                    "client_tin_no" : "4564565",
                    "client_email_id":"abc@gmail.com",
                    "head_office_name" : "ABC",
                    "office_name" : "asd234",
                    "office_email_id": "zxc@gmail.com",
                    "office_contact":"022-27547119",
                    "gst_number":"CGST786876876",
                    "office_country":"India",
                    "office_state":"gujrat",
                    "office_district":"vadodara",
                    "office_taluka":"kachh",
                    "office_city":"vadodara",
                    "office_street":"New rode 21",
                    "office_pincode":"2344445",
                    "contact_person_name":"prasad",
                    "contact_person_designation":"DM",
                    "contact_person_number":"456754655",
                    "contact_person_email":"asd@gmail.com",
                    "contact_person_mobile":"5675545654",
                    "bank_name":"Kotak",
                    "branch":"vashi",
                    "ifsc_code":"KKBK786988",
                    "account_number":"56756765765765",
                    "account_name":"Prathamesh",
                    "document_type":"pan",
                    "document":"{www.sendgrid.com/pan,www.sendgrid.com/adhar}",
                    "created_by":"Prathamseh",
                    "updated_by":"prasad",
                    "bank_details" : [
                                        {   
                                            "bank_name":"Kalki Bank",
                                            "branch":"nagpada",
                                            "ifsc_code":"BOI786988",
                                            "account_number":"56756765765765",
                                            "account_name":"Tushar"
                                        },
                                        {   
                                            "bank_name":"Kalki Chartted",
                                            "branch":"chinchpokli",
                                            "ifsc_code":"ST786988",
                                            "account_number":"56756765765765",
                                            "account_name":"Tushar"
                                        }
                                     ],
                    "document_details" : [
                                            {   
                                                "user_id":"CL15664751132746806000",
                                                "document_type":"Kalki's Passport",
                                                "document":"www.sendgrid.com/pan"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "user_id":"CL15664751132746806000",
                                                "document_type":"Kalki's Visa",
                                                "document":"www.sendgrid.com/visa"
                                            }
                                         ]               
                }
             ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one `ClientDetails` objects with the provided `client_id`. Either use unique constraint on model or use `filter` to retrieve in such case and update both or whichever you want.

```
client_obj = None
clients = cls.objects.filter(client_id = client_id)
if clients:
    client_obj = clients[0]   // you can retrieve object by some order here
    // do rest of your things here
```

N.B: Do the same for BankDetails and DocumentDetails too. Use `filter` instead of `get`.

Comment: ClientDetails is updating properly but the issue is in Bank & DocumentDetail. from view.py data is properly sent to update_bank_details. so should i have do the same for update bank method

Comment: @PrathameshDoke Yes. As I already mentioned in the answer, you have to use `filter` instead of `get`. Same as `clients`.

Comment: neither get works nor filter, i have tried  it and also i have tried .update() and .save() but none of it works.

Comment: I have updated it. i have also tried with your method and also with the .save & .update() but its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198354/discussion-between-prathamesh-doke-and-md-khairul-basar).

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you have in your database two rows with the same `bank_details_id` but you are trying to get only one here: `cls.objects.get(bank_details_id = bank_details_id)`.

Comment: bank_details_id is different but user_id is same for two rows.